# Hibernate, making a native sql query and getting column names for the things on get()

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Given this example:

```
    NativeQuery query = query();
    try ( ScrollableResults scroll = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY) ) {
        int i = -1; while ( scroll.next() ) {
            ++i; // DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
```

When I do scroll.next() i can do `scroll.get(i)`;

However, I can not see a way to get the column name that you normally get on a select. Normally you would on a `ResultSet` get the `columName` for `i`.

On that class is getResultSet() but is private which would have allowed:

```
  scroll.getResultSet().getMetaData().getColumnName(i)
```

But is now not possible, and not pretty even if it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work with a native query, why don't you use the JDBC API directly?

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    }
});
```

Like suggested in your similar question here: [hibernate get underlying sql resutlset. nativequery is very limiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64161381/hibernate-get-underlying-sql-resutlset-nativequery-is-very-limiting/64167706)