# hibernate get underlying sql resutlset. nativequery is very limiting

Tags: hibernate

hibernate get underlying sql resutlset. nativequery is very limiting. i need to execute a regular sql query while being able to access the resultset.

`org.hibernate.internal.ScrollableResultsImpl` has protected access on `getResultSet`. how can i provide my own implementation that will expose `resultset`.

I need a resultset to be able to get the metadata such as column names. they are there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can operate on the underlying `Connection` directly, without resorting to a native query:

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    }
});
```

Comment: Only problem is i have to convert the named query to a preparedstatement using ? and convert it to such. I don't get why they dont expose it. so blatant. i can reflect access it, or use the deprecated resulttransformer perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should state what you actually want to achieve rather than just complaining about what doesn't work for you. The designers of this Hibernate API maybe didn't see the need for exposing the JDBC result set at that point because the usage could lead to subtle bugs.  I personally don't see the need either and can't imagine your use case.

If you use a HQL query, why do you even need the SQL aliases? You could use the `javax.persistence.Tuple` as result type to get access to values by alias like in the following example:

```
TypedQuery<Tuple> query = em.createNamedQuery("myQuery", Tuple.class);
List<Tuple> resultList = query.getResultList();
resultList.get(0).get("alias1", Integer.class);
```

Comment: When you are doing getResulList hibernate is already walking over the result set once. There is no need for me to walk over it again. "Designers of this Hibernate API did not see a need... bla bla bla" what a terrible excuse. Their limited vision is limiting us others wanting to do something else with a result, when all they had to do is allow us access. I just reflect get the underlying private resultset. Thanks!

Comment: what i am want to do is perform a normal sql query myself and output the result from the result set. there is no way to get the column names with scrollablebullshit. that is a major problem. hibernate has a way for you to iterate without the resultset, but you should never design an api that uses another api and not ensure access to the underlying one as well, in case you forgot to implement something someone can easily still do whatever the underlying one can.

Comment: I think your tone is a little rude so I'd like to ask you to rethink what kind of language you use here.
What's the big deal of walking the result multiple times? If you want to walk it only once, then use the ResultTransformer API: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-resulttransformer/
You say you want to use an SQL query and use JDBC, fine then use what was proposed by @guillaume.

Comment: "Maybe you should state what you actually want to achieve rather than just complaining about what doesn't work for you." You started the rudeness. The problem is that it is unnecessary and if you are building an API then you do not want that extra unnecessary layer. The resulttransformer is possible and works, but I just don't see why the hell they would hide the underlying stuff that they rely on. Makes zero sense and is poor API design. ResultTransformer is probably all dandy, but a lot of stuff occurs before that layer is actually called, and there is no need.

Comment: I also have a bunch of code that works with native sql and native jdbc resultsets. Forcing the use of resulttransformer makes it hard to use and would lead to undue redundancy.

Comment: So you think the initial "i can't believe they've made this f*** hard." was appropriate? I asked why you would want SQL aliases since these are generated and it makes absolutely no sense to me to want to know the aliases. I often read complaints about something not working on SO and this bothers me sometimes because I always have to ask what the actual intent is to be able to provide help. It's a lot easier to help when someone asks "how to do X, I tried A, B C". The only layers between JDBC and ResultTransformer is hydration(to create entities) and caching.

Comment: i want to know the actual column names. I said I was generating a native sql query MYSELF. I am building it. I am not asking Hibernate to generate it for me. Whatever  is returned, I would like to know the column names that was returned. That seems impossible with scrollable. Scrollable is useless, since you can only do index based, positional read. There is no way to map the index to a column name. When you do an sql query you get rows, in columns, named. With native JDBC, you can read the columns from the resultset.

Comment: For some reason, hibernate has decided to A) not provide this access to this information that exists in resultset.metadata, and B) has decided to hide the underlying resultset, in order to force you to rely and USE their API to do what you would nornally do on a JDBC resultset. It forces you to tie yourself harder to hiberante, when there is no need since both actions are equivalent, and the underlying is more pure. I set up my jdbc using hibernate with c3p0 and therefore, I would like to execute my freaking sql queries using that connection pool.

Comment: However, doing that, Hibernate provides you no way to go truly native and independent, using the underlying sql connection to execute jdbc based queries. Instead it forces you to use its own flawed API's TO and FROM the JDBC connection, never exposing it. This is evil. Redhat, JBOSS might want to tie you in, while I am trying to move from Hibernate to at least start generating my SQL queries without using Hibernate HQL, Criteria Queries and instead rely on generating the SQL using other, better and fully flexible libraries.

Comment: I see, I was wrongly assuming from your comment here(https://stackoverflow.com/a/64161754/412446) that you are using a named hql query. I'm not sure though why you want to use a Hibernate API at all when you could just use JDBC. The ScrollableResults API does not expose internals because I think the same API is used when you scroll HQL queries and any tinkering with the underlying result set could lead to bugs.

Comment: Criteria queries are dandy, but try using postgresql lateral queries, or postgresql functions, group statements, complex projecttions and so forth. It is limited and comlex to get right. It does not support all that an underlying database does. In SQL we know how that looks like. Maybe  can perhaps use ResultTransformer to read out the columns, but I don't see the freaking need to do that, nor hook myself into that. Why is the resultset not exposed. It makes no sense. There are other things available on resultset that are not exposed either.

Comment: You can just inject the datasource that you configured for Hibernate and use JDBC directly or use the API that was suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64161754/412446 for going truly native. If some other API works better for you then use it. Hibernate is a tool like any other. Use it when you benefit from it and use something different if more appropriate.

Comment: Look, if you think exposing the RS is something that Hibernate should support, then create an issue and maybe create a PR to expose it. But be prepared to answer the question "why not just use JDBC directly then?". There is apparently no benefit in using Hibernate for this use case, so why do you want to use Hibernate so bad for this?

Comment: I can forgo to use hibernate completly and go towards the connection myself, however, then I would have to configure it with a connection pool preferably, similar to c3p0. I am using hibernate for jpa entities and inserts which for now, seems quite ok (not great) so I am unable to fully forgo it. I have a mixed usage for advanced multi table searches, it is better to go the SQL way.

Comment: Criteria queries are great, but A) they rely on a source entity class to connect all others, and B) they are extremely limited in what you can express. Groups, distinct, projections and what not. JOOQL was born for this reason, full flexibility. Hibernate just makes it a bit harder to do both.

Comment: Hibernate is an abstraction and tries to be compatible with many DBMS. Supporting lateral joins or other features is not always that easy because not all DBMS support these features. This will likely change in the future, but right now that's how it is. If you are interested in using these advanced features on top of the JPA model you can take a look at what Blaze-Persistence has to offer: https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage as it supports lateral joins and much more

Comment: I can use JDBC directly, but then I would not get the connection from the already configured conneciton pool. Ratehr than setup all this complex crap, with a secondary connection pool, I should be able to use the existing pool. I can get a connectoin from hibernate as the answer as indicated, but then we have to map the named parts to ? marks. Why I am frustrated is that, all Hiberante had to do was to just provide access. That is API 101. You use the underlying, there needs to be a vigilante mode, always.

Comment: Wow, that looks awesome! I will look into that for the future.

Comment: Normally, the connection pooling is not done directly in Hibernate. If you are in a Java EE or Spring environment you usually have a pooling datasource, so you can just inject the datasource and use connections from it. Hibernate will use the same datasource, so that part should be solved.

Comment: I use this: https://imgur.com/a/90WKyB0  Not sure how to get the underlying one. Eitherway, currently I got acceess to the resultset using reflection. It is there, but private. So I am fine now.

Comment: Accessing the result set by column names is darn slow btw. because every lookup will do an additional hash map lookup behind the scenes. Since you mentioned performance, this might be interesting to you. Hibernate switched to use positional access internally in version 6 because of this performance hit. Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views also use positional access behind the scenes, so if it fits your use case, you can have a nice abstraction and at the same time improved performance.

Comment: I read the columns once from resultset and map them from column to index so it is a get columns once operation.